# Combine duplicate rows in a loop vba

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, duplicates

I want to combine duplicate rows with the same A and C columns values and sum their cells values for the column B  (by adding the value of the textbox2 from the duplicate to the original). My problem is about the condition of the "If" in the Loop. It doesn't consider those conditions when I have duplicates and just add a new row. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Enter()


ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"  
Dim lastrow As Long

With Sheets("Sheet2")

 lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

 For x = lastrow To 3 Step -1
   For y = 3 To lastrow
       
       If .Cells(x, 1).Value = .Cells(y, 1).Value And .Cells(x, 3).Value = .Cells(y, 3).Value And x > y Then
       
       .Cells(y, 8).Value = .Cells(y, 8).Value + TextBox2.Text
       .Cells(y, 2).Value = .Cells(y, 2).Value + TextBox2.Text
       .Rows(lastrow).EntireRow.Delete
           
      Else

       .Cells(lastrow + 1, 8).Value = TextBox2.Text
       .Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
       .Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
       .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text
       
         Exit For
      End If

   Next y
 Next x

End With

End Sub
```

Here's a picture of the data
[image]

There's no blank cell in the column H (I changed the color of the font to make it invisible).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your data? Can you sort the data first so that similar values are together?

Comment: @SJR Okay I edited it and put a picture, no I can't sort the data.

Comment: It looks like you trying to combine existing duplicate rows and enter a new row within the same button method, is that correct  ?

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do!

Comment: The else is made for adding new rows who aren't duplicates.

Comment: Not sure why you have 2 loops, are there existing duplicate records before the new record is entered ? If not, a single loop (or find) would identify any single existing record so you could either summate the quantities else add the new record.

Comment: If the code works well it is not suppose to have duplicates before my new entry. I am really new at VBA and I didn't find out how to do that for 2 columns. I know there are better ways to do this but I haven't found any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a primary key by joining the 2 columns with tilde ~ and use a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to locate duplicates.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long, iTarget As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dict As Object, sKey As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' build dictionary and
    ' consolidate any existing duplicates, scan up
    For iRow = iLastRow To 3 Step -1

        ' create composite primary key
        sKey = LCase(ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value) & "~" & Format(ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

        If dict.exists(sKey) Then
            iTarget = dict(sKey)
            ' summate and delete
            ws.Cells(iTarget, 2) = ws.Cells(iTarget, 2) + ws.Cells(iRow, 2)
            ws.Cells(iTarget, 8) = ws.Cells(iTarget, 8) + ws.Cells(iRow, 8)
            ws.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            dict(sKey) = iRow
        End If
    Next

    ' add new record from form using dictionary to locate any existing
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    sKey = LCase(TextBox1.Text) & "~" & Format(DateValue(TextBox3.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    If dict.exists(sKey) Then
        iTarget = dict(sKey)
        ws.Cells(iTarget, 2) = ws.Cells(iTarget, 2) + TextBox2.Text
        ws.Cells(iTarget, 8) = ws.Cells(iTarget, 8) + TextBox2.Text
    Else
        iTarget = iLastRow + 1
        ws.Cells(iTarget, 1) = TextBox1.Text
        ws.Cells(iTarget, 2) = TextBox2.Text
        ws.Cells(iTarget, 3) = TextBox3.Text
        ws.Cells(iTarget, 8) = TextBox2.Text
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it works pretty well! I just change that part _ws.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete_  for that _ws.Rows(iLastRow + 1).EntireRow.Delete_ because when the column A to C were empty below the original duplicate it was deleting it.

Comment: Do you know if there's an equivalent of the Scripting.Dictionary for Mac?

Comment: If someone need to use it on Mac (cause the Scripting.Dictionary is not working), I able to make it work by downloading a VBA-dictionary [https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary], by importing the _dictionary.cls_ files into my workbook project and by changing a line in the code `Set dict = New Dictionary` instead of `Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.